# How can I scroll to the end of a textbox in UWP?

Tags: c#, user-interface, uwp, textbox

I'm working on a project and have decided to use UWP instead of using winforms (which I am more comfortable with). I have a very simple `TextBox` that I am using as a way to log data being sent and received. Here is a simple example of what it looks like:

[Textbox view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YrEm.png)

Here is what the XAML code for it:

```
<Grid>
    <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="18,862,0,0" Text="Logs " TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
    <TextBox x:Name="LogsTextBox" Margin="18,886,18,0" Text="Welcome to Tiger" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="88" FontFamily="Courier New" FontSize="12" AcceptsReturn="True" ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Visible" IsReadOnly="True"/>
</Grid>
```

At the current moment of time, my `TextBox` is wrapped by the default `Grid` that I got when I first started the project.

Here is a look at the method used to add lines to the `LogsTextBox`

```
/// <summary>
/// A method used to log data to the LogsTextBox
/// </summary>
/// <param name="LogString">The string to be logged</param>
private void Log(string LogString)
{
    string TimeString = DateTime.Now.ToString("hh-mm-ss-tt");
    LogsTextBox.Text += $"\n[{TimeString}]: {LogString}";
}
```

As can be seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0YrEm.png) the data being logged is now larger than the height of the `TextBox`. Is there anyway I could make it so that every time the method `Log` is called, the `LogsTextBox` would auto scroll to the end?

I've found a couple of solutions on here but they didnt seeme to work for me. Namely these:

1. [Solution 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56164482/uwp-textbox-to-auto-scroll-down-as-text-is-received)
2. [Solution 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40114620/uwp-c-sharp-scroll-to-the-bottom-of-textbox)

Any help I could get would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Hi, If the answer works, please accept anfd vote, in order others can find the answer conveniently. thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a matter of fact, solution 2's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40114621/7068790) and [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41898598/7068790) both works.

[image]